# How to make this multidrop form to array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have a multidrop form at this fiddle : Here's [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/orocduded/y5dv3z8p/)! . at this form only can add multidrop 3 times, i want to make always add this multidrop, and how to save the array data into sql

```
<div id="Yes1">
<label for="name" >Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name1" name="name1">
<br><br>
<label for="multiDrop" >Multi Drop</label>
<select name="multiDrop1" id="multiDrop1">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Y">YES</option>
<option value="N">NO</option>
</select>
<br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @NegiRox i only can add 3 multi drop , i want add maybe 10 multidrop but make that code more simple than i create same code until 10 times

Comment: Use classes instead of ids to mark/locate your elements, and use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to simplify the assignment of event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use following approach:

- get your repetitive block HTML into a variable;
- listen for changes of drop down (using event delegation, selecting by `class` rather than `id`);
- modify necessary attributes (names, id's, etc) based on global counter to distinguish those dynamic blocks;

```js
const block = `
 <div class="block">
  <div class="yes">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="name"></input>
   <label>Multi Drop</label>
   <select class="multiDrop">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Y">YES</option>
    <option value="N">NO</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
`;
const addAnotherBlock = () => {
  $('#wrapper').append(block);
  $('.name:last').attr('name',i++);
};
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(() => addAnotherBlock());

$('#wrapper').on('change', '.multiDrop', function(){
 if($(this).val() == 'Y') addAnotherBlock();
  else if($(this).val() == 'N' && $('.block').length > 1 && !$(this).closest('.block').is('.block:last')){
    $(this).closest('.block').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: how to remove the multidrop if i choose no?

Comment: is that what you mean?

Comment: Check @Orocduded Its only removing last element. Try entering name in the 5th input box out of 10 input boxes. and try to remove that 5th input box by selecting No. Even if you try to remove that 5th block, it will remove last block.

Comment: Nevertheless, if we enjoy catching bugs together, your solution allows to delete all the dynamic blocks up to the empty page; also, it does unnecessary cloning input field contents, which user, most probably, is going to need to edit and, if 'NO' is selected within the last drop-down, you can't proceed adding blocks before unselecting/selecting previous 'YES'.

Answer (score 2):

Check here to add and remove your elements as per your requirement.
You can remove only that block which you selected No for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".multidrop", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Y') {
      $clone = $(this).closest(".Yes").clone();
      var num = parseInt($(".Yes:last").attr("data-index")) + 1;
      $clone.attr("data-index", num);
      $clone.attr("id", $clone.attr("id").replace(/\d+/, num));
      $clone.find("input,select").each(function() {
        var name = ($(this).attr("name")).replace(/\d+/, num);
        var id = ($(this).attr("id")).replace(/\d+/, num);
        $(this).attr("name", name);
        $(this).attr("id", id);
      });
      $clone.insertAfter(".Yes:last"); //Add field html
    } else if ($(this).val() == "N" && $(".Yes").length > 1) {
      $(this).closest(".Yes").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Yes1" class="Yes" data-index="1">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" class="name">
  <label for="multiDrop">Multi Drop</label>
  <select name="multiDrop1" id="multiDrop1" class="multidrop">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="Y">YES</option>
    <option value="N">NO</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
</div>
```